# Failing to Compile Data to Render in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am currently trying to fetch data from a JSON file and get it to render to a researchPage. Nothing I do seems to be working. I would like to fetch the data and put it into some sort of a table or visualization. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. I am currently receiving the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

In the data directory I have

damon-data.json (this is a large file and would be impossible to place here, so I am placing a small portion)

```
{

    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "issflightplan",
            "_type": "issflightplan",
            "_key": "IDP-ISSFLIGHTPLAN-0000000000000447",
            "_version": 1,
            "_score": null,
            "ContentType": {
                "__deferred": {
                    "uri": "https://bi.sp.iss.nasa.gov/Sites/FP/_api/Web/Lists(guid'a9421c5b-186a-4b14-b7b2-4b88ee8fab95')/Items(252)/ContentType"
                }
```

then in the same directory I have

data.js - My thought was that I would fetch the data here and pass it to the research page using props

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import data from '../data/damon-data.json'
import axios from 'axios';


class Data extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = ({
            dataSet: []
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let url = data;
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.hits)
                this.setState({
                    dataSet: response.data.hits
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
}
```

researchPage.js - This is where the data should render (once I get it to render here I thought I could begin working to place it into a table. Unless there is a better way to go about it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class researchPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(

            <div>
                {this.props.data.map((dataSet, index) => (
                   return <p>{dataSet.hits}</p>
                ))}
            </div>

        )
    }
}
export default researchPage
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/menu/navbar";
import Home from './pages/home/home'
import Explore from './pages/explore/explore'
import search from './pages/search/search'
import researchPage from "./pages/researchPage/reasearchPage";
import Query from './pages/query/query'
import Visualize from "./pages/visualize/visualize";
import Analyze from "./pages/analyze/analyze";
import Configure from "./pages/configure/configure";

class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
                <Route path="/explore" component={Explore} exact/>
                <Route path="/search" component={search} exact/>
                <Route path="/query" component={Query} exact/>
                <Route path="/visualize" component={Visualize} exact/>
                <Route path="/analyze" component={Analyze} exact/>
                <Route path="/configure" component={Configure} exact/>
                <Route path="/research" component={researchPage} exact/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Are you passing the data from the Data component to researchPage? Can't see code for that. Are you able to get data in your console.log(response.data.hits)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do, not sure if I am missing something on passing the Data component to the researchPage. I am not seeing anything in the console for data at all. I did place the following error that I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: So you are importing some data from a local json file. Then you use axios to call a URL, which, based on your code, appears to be the data you just imported from the json file. I am super confused.

Comment: How/Where are you using the researchPage and how are you passing data to it?

Comment: Sanish, I just added the App.js and index.js. This is my main issue, trying to figure out how to pass the data from the data component to the researchPage. I know that I am not doing it right, but I can not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think that I thought I could create the state in the data component and then pass the props to the researchPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have done all steps correct, there is a mistake in your code right away, that you are saving `response.data.hits` and again trying to map it like `<p>{dataSet.hits}</p>` which will simply treated as `response.data.hits.hits` because according to your code `dataSet` is actually `hits` array. So you might only want to do

```
    this.setState({
        dataSet: response.data
    })
```

Other than that, it seems you aren't passing the data to `researchPage` component. The simplest way to test your data will be to call the API directly in `researchPage` component, and then instead of using it from props, you will get it from state:

```
        <div>
            {this.state.data?.map((dataSet, index) => (
                return <p>{dataSet.hits}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
```

OR if you want to stick with your previous code, you'll have to do:

```
        <div>
            {this.state.data?.map((dataSet, index) => (
                return <p>{dataSet}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
```

Now, if you want to keep your data fetching logic separate, then you have to go with some state management tool, (which I assume will be new for you), OR test it with localStorage OR you have to stick with Parent Child pattern, like in the Data component call
`<ResearchPage data={this.state.dataSet} />` (not recommended, just mentioning), OR you can do an ugly solution i.e calling the data APIs in App.js component and then passing it to components from there.

Comment: tried the solution and getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null researchPage.render
  3 | class researchPage extends Component {
  4 |     render() {
  5 |         return (
> 6 |          <div>
  7 |              {this.state.data?.map((dataSet, index) => {
  8 |                  return <p>{dataSet}</p>
  9 |              })}

Comment: can you please share complete code for researchPage component. It seems from the error that state is not initialized properly. and we are using data before it gets intialized as  render executes before didMount. Simple solution will be to apply a check that whether data exists:
{this.state.data && this.state.data?.map((dataSet, index) //rest of the code